# Loading multiple dataframes to Power BI at once using python code

Tags: python, powerbi

I am unable to load all of my data frames at once in Power BI using the python code option in 'Get Data' whereas individually selecting data frames does work and loads them in Power BI.

I have created 4 data frames using python code and while using the code in Power BI 'Get Data', the data frames do show up but i am not able to load all of them in Power BI all at once. but if i individually select the dfs I am able to load them successfully in Power BI.

This is the error i encounter in Power BI

```
Load
Count_By_Stat4_df
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
Count_By_Stat3_df
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
Count_By_Stat2_df
ADO.NET: Python script error.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 27, in <module>
 s3.download_file(bucket_name, Product_Metrics_s3_path, Product_Metrics_local_path)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 172, in download_file
 extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
 future.result()
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 106, in result
 return self._coordinator.result()
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 265, in result
 raise self._exception
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 126, in __call__
 return self._execute_main(kwargs)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 150, in _execute_main
 return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\download.py", line 603, in _main
 osutil.rename_file(fileobj.name, final_filename)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 271, in rename_file
 rename_file(current_filename, new_filename)
 File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\compat.py", line 25, in rename_file
 os.remove(new_filename)
 PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\pbi\\Product_Metrics.xlsx'
Counts_By_Stat1_df
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
test_metrics_df
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
Close
```

```
    for file in glob.glob('*AddressFabric_Product_Metrics.xlsx'):
        Counts_By_Stat1_df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet1')
        Counts_By_Stat2_df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet2')
        Counts_By_Stat3_df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet3')
        Counts_By_Stat4_df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet4')
```

Comment: Have you tried closing/disposing the connection after each sheet load? It looks like the file is locked due to 'Counts_By_Stat1_df' retaining a link to the excel sheet